How to request user for precise location?
Using Geolocator package, when requesting location permission user can select for approximate location. Or user can also turn off precise location from settings. We can get location accuracy that user has selected from -> (LocationAccuracyStatus.reduced || LocationAccuracyStatus.precise) but how to request user again for precise location permission?
So initially if approximate location permissions are granted, then after checking LocationAccuracyStatus value is reduced, I called Geolocator.requestPermission() again but it did not show system ui popup again.
 LocationPermission permission;
  permission = await Geolocator.checkPermission();
  if (permission == LocationPermission.denied) {
      permission = await Geolocator.requestPermission();
      if (permission == LocationPermission.denied) {
          MainUtils.showTopSnackbar(
           "Location Permissions are required to use the app",
           duration: const Duration(seconds: 5));
           return;
       }
 }

//CHECKING LOCATION ACCURACY
var accuracy = await Geolocator.getLocationAccuracy();
if (accuracy == LocationAccuracyStatus.reduced) {
   permission = await Geolocator.requestPermission(); //REQUESTING PERMISSION AGAIN
}

https://developer.android.com/develop/sensors-and-location/location/permissions#upgrade-to-precise

Reference image

I think you cannot programmatically request an upgrade from an approximate to a precise location. Once a user has chosen an approximate location, they must manually change this in system settings.However You can redirect user to system permission settings of your app
  if (accuracy == LocationAccuracyStatus.reduced) {
  final bool shouldOpenSettings = await showDialog(
    context: context,
    builder: (context) => AlertDialog(
      title: Text('Precise Location Needed'),
      content: Text(
        'This app requires precise location to function properly. '
        'Would you like to change this in settings?'
      ),

you can use method channel to call native code
private fun openAppSettings() {
val intent = Intent(Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS)
val uri = Uri.fromParts("package", packageName, null)
intent.data = uri
startActivity(intent)}

method channel
 import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

class NativeSettingsHandler {
  static const platform = MethodChannel('com.yourapp/settings');

  Future<void> openAppSettingsNative() async {
    try {
      await platform.invokeMethod('openAppSettings');
    } on PlatformException catch (e) {
      print("Failed to open app settings: '${e.message}'.");
    }
  }
}

